# Angular JS showing user error message after ajax post in a div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple form, when posting then on error I want to feedback to the user the error message on screen in a div box. What would be the best way to do this?

**This is my controller so far:**

```
.controller("CompanyUserFormCtrl", ['$scope', 'Restangular', 'CbgenRestangular', '$q',
    function ($scope, Restangular, CbgenRestangular, $q) {
        // Submit form
        $scope.submit = function () {
            var post_data = {email: $scope.email}
            var post_call = CbgenRestangular.all('accounts/create-company').post(post_data)

            $q.when(post_call.then(

                function (object) {
                   // on success
                },
                function (object) {
                     // on error
                    // render in a div some error message here <----------
                }
            ))
        }
    }])
```

**My form:**

```
<div ng-controller="CompanyUserFormCtrl">
    form stuff
    <div class="col-lg-offset-3 col-lg-9">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="submit()">Register</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Do I need a new directive if so could I see an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an **ng-show** directive to the div containing the error and set it's value to true when the error occurs.

e.g.

```
<div ng-show='createFailed'>Oh dear - create company failed</div>
```

and in your error handler in the controller:

```
$scope.createFailed = true;
```

Comment: I tried that by added $scope.error = "test" but nothing happened i.e. the ng-show="{{error}}" did not display

Comment: in the Dom I see this but no message test <div ng-show="true" class="ng-binding ng-hide">test</div>

Comment: The ng-show directive should have ng-show='createFailed' and not ng-show='{{createFailed}}'

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a example and I'm very new to Angular, but you can use [ngShow](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow) directive:

```
<div ng-show="error.length">{{error}}</div>
```

and like:

```
        $q.when(post_call.then(

            function (object) {
               // on success
            },
            function (object) {
                $scope.error = object.errorText;
            }
        ))
```

EDIT: now [working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9mTSB/)

EDIT2: use ".length"-version!

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can use 
    <label>
      Username:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.username" name="username"
        required
        call-back />
    </label>

    <ng-messages for="signUpForm.username.$error" ng-if="signUpForm.username.$dirty">
      <ng-message when="unique" class="error">This is taken</ng-message>
    </ng-messages>

    m.directive('callBack', function(isUsernameAvailable) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
          ngModel.$asyncValidators.unique = isUsernameAvailable;
        }
      };
    });


m.factory('isExist', function($q, $http) {
  return function(username) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('/api/emp/' + username).then(function() {
      // Found the user, therefore not unique.
      deferred.reject();
    }, function() {
      // User not found, therefore unique!
      deferred.resolve();
    });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
});
```